# How to convert Uint8Array to a float in javascript?

Tags: javascript, floating-point-conversion

I have an `ArrayBuffer` that I convert to a `Uint8Array` so that I can use traditional array access with square brackets and gather a subarray.  Now that I have the correct set of 4 bytes that describe the 32-bit (little endian) floating point number, I don't seem to have an easy way to convert to the floating point value:

```
var startIndex = 2;
var buffer = new Uint8Array(data)
buffer.subarray(startIndex, startIndex + 4);
var myNumber = ?uint8ArrayToFloat(buffer);
console.log(myNumber);
```

I'm new to JavaScript and am still looking around different docs...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`DataView.getFloat32`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView/getFloat32). First, you would create the `DataView` from the original `ArrayBuffer` (or the `Uint8Array`). getFloat32 takes an optional parameter that allows you to specify the endianess of the data you are reading.

Comment: how can you create a `DataView` from a `Uint8Array`?  I'm getting the error that my first argument to the `DataView` constructor must be an `ArrayBuffer`

Comment: ah, you have to realize when you're going against the flow sometimes.  refactored everything to pass around array buffers instead.